# Аутентификация через Гугл // Веб Формы ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, asp.net-webforms

Следуя [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/checkout-and-payment-with-paypal) в классе `Startup` идентифицирую "secret" и "id"

```
       {
          ClientId = "Client ID for Web application => аккаунт гугл с настройками приложения", 
          ClientSecret = "Client secret => там же секрет"
          // так тоже проверила, хотя она задается по умолчанию CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-google")      
        });
```

Гугл аккаунт
[image: настройка аккаунта гугл]

При попытке аутентифицироваться через гугл никуда не перенаправляет

*(три дня назад перенаправлял на страницу гугл и
после ввода аккаунта и пароля возвращал на страницу /Account,
потом переустановила систему на Windows11 и
теперь просто отстается на странице /Account и молчит...)*

начала отладку, останавливаюсь на загрузке странице...а именно на `loginInfo == null`

```
        {
            // Обработка результата от поставщика проверки подлинности в запросе
            ProviderName = IdentityHelper.GetProviderNameFromRequest(Request);
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ProviderName))
            {
                RedirectOnFail();
                return;
            }
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
                var signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
                var loginInfo = Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfo();
                if (loginInfo == null)
                {
//Входит в этот if при отладке  
                    RedirectOnFail();
                    return;
                }
............
```

если это localhost, то почему в примере в данной [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/checkout-and-payment-with-paypal#:%7E:text=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E.) не вижу об этом ничего

[image: localhostGoogle]

Comment: localhost не может быть хостом авторизации. Это локальный адрес на вашей машине и значение он имеет только для вашей машины.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(три дня назад перенаправлял на страницу гугл и после ввода аккаунта и пароля возвращал на страницу /Account, потом переустановила систему на Windows11 и теперь просто отстается на странице /Account и молчит...)*

Именно потому, что Windows был переустановлен, localhost изменился у приложения, и тот пользователь, что вы добавили в вашем гугл аккаунте, уже не знает данного localhost-a.

То есть если следовать инстуркции/документации, то можно использовать ваш localhost и авторизоваться через гугл, НО важно очень внимательно обратить внимание на три аспекта:

1. Client ID
2. Client Secret
3. и соответсвтенно верный localhost

в файле Startup.Auth откоментировать идентификацию и выставить ID и Secret ИМЕННО того пользователя, которому Вы открыли доступ на Вашем гугл аккаунте, происходит merge и вы спокойно через localhost пользуетесь своим приложением.
а localhost сохраняете в Вашем гугл аккаунте все для того же пользователя, и для каждого нового пользователя нужно открывать новый доступ
в [этой документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/checkout-and-payment-with-paypal) очень подробно все изложено, просто внимательней на три аспекта, в вашем/моем случае вы пропустили проверку localhost-а

[ссылка, чтобы настроить пользователя в вашем гугл аккаунте](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]